# Hardhat smart contract deployment script using multiple wallets

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

In hardhat config file I am able to provide multiple wallets via an array in the account field. How do I access the 2nd signer? I would like to have a single run deploy script to deploy two contracts each with a different signer.

I know I can just split the deployment into two each with their own config, but my use case is a 12 contract codebase with intricate dependencies between them and I'd like to deploy all of them in one go.

I'm using this approach to deploy: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/deploying

Would be great to have a similar example for the second signer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the example deploy script from the hardhat documentation:

```
const Lock = await ethers.getContractFactory("Lock");
const lock = await Lock.deploy(unlockTime, { value: lockedAmount });

await lock.deployed();
```

Now I will deploy the same Lock contract using 2 signers:

Step 1: Get the signers using hardhat ethers.

```
const signers = await ethers.getSigners();
```

This gives an array of signers.

Step 2: Deploy using the first signer:

```
const lock1 = await Lock.connect(signers[0]).deploy(unlockTime, { value: lockedAmount });

await lock1.deployed();
```

Step 3: Deploy using the second signer:

```
const lock2 = await Lock.connect(signers[1]).deploy(unlockTime, { value: lockedAmount });

await lock2.deployed();
```

Another way is to do this entirely using ethers.js. I have an example of this on my GitHub: https://github.com/codeTIT4N/axelar-two-way-nft-example/blob/main/scripts/deploy.js

Comment: i used the optional 2nd argument of `getContractFactory` where you can provide the signer